# 'GARCH - extreme value theory - copula' approach to estimate risk measures in R

Tags: time-series, backtesting, garch, value-at-risk, copula

I'm reading about this approach of using GARCH-EVT-copula methodology to separate univariate and joint estimation and then estimate for example VaR and ES. I wanted to try something similar, but my attempt failed miserably. Anyone of you sees a mistake in the methodology outlined below? Any hint is appreciated!

I took a few series, computed log returns, and multiplied them by -1 (so that I have losses on the right and returns on the left). Then I used this approach:

> 1) ARMA-GARCH fitting according to AIC (using the `rugarch` package);
>
> 2) obtain standardized residuals $z_t = \frac{\epsilon_t}{\sigma_t}$;
>
> 3) semi-parametric modeling of $z_t$ using a generalized Pareto
>   distribution for upper and lower tails (thresholds at 10% and 90%) and
>   Gaussian kernel for the interior part (using the `spd` package);
>
> 4) transformation in uniform margins using the `pspd` command from the
>   previous package;
>
> 5) copula fitting using an Archimedean copula model via maximum
>   likelihood (since ML could not be evaluated in all points, I
>   transformed the uniform margins in pseudo-observations using the
>   `pobs` command before fitting);
>
> 6) since I want a time-varying copula approach, I use a moving window
>   of 1000 observations to estimate a time-varying Archimedean copula
>   parameter, and fit an ARIMA in order to do forecasting;
>
> 7) given predicted copula parameters (thanks to previous ARIMA
>   specification), N copula realizations are simulated from day $t+1$ to
>   $T$;
>
> 8) using the `qspd` command, I transform copula realizations back in
>   standardized residuals $z_{t}$;
>
> 9) I insert estimated $z_t$ back in ARMA-GARCH specification, compute
>   log returns,  transform in simple returns, and calculate return of
>   equally weighted portfolio;
>
> 10) now I have N returns for each day, and can compute required VaR as
>   the $\alpha$-quantile (90, 95, 97.5, 99, ...).

Now the staggering surprise: this methodology failed miserably for me for relatively moderate quantiles (90, 95 and 97.5) and more extreme quantiles (99, 99.5, 99.9). I obtain a number of violations which is WAY more than expected.
Any reason why? Is there a mistake in the steps mentioned?

Comment: Are you using actual historical asset returns or simulated returns for this?

Comment: I'm using 2000 historical daily log returns to estimate the ARMA-GARCH coefficients, the GPD parameters and the time series of the copula parameter. Once I have this time series, I estimate the ARIMA so that I forecast the 1-step ahead parameter and simulate N copula realizations for (t+1); then again forecasting 1-step ahead parameter and simulation of N realizations for (t+2) and so on until the end of the forecasting period. Then steps 8 to 10.

Comment: I suggest you use a Monte Carlo simulated returns with a normal distribution to help you debug your problem.

Comment: John, may I ask you what you mean exactly? Simulate random draws from a multivariate normal and interpret these as returns? Also how would I calibrate mean vector and covariance matrix if that's the case, with sample mean and covariance?

Comment: Your procedure consists of a number of individual steps. You could try finding out at which step it fails, and then try to understand why.

Comment: Hi Kondo! Did you find the fault eventually?